# Delay and incomplete loading of the page when using parameter with GET route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes, get, delay

When I extend a GET route with a parameter, the page is not loaded completely and there is delay in loading the page, so what is the solution?

This is the route

```
Route::get('/Report/{sub_date_number}', [reportController::class,'show_orders_report'])->Middleware('isAdmin');
```

and this is the function definition of show_order_report function in the controller

```
    public function show_orders_report($sub_date_number){
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just wondering how big your report data? and you have to settings your php.ini if your data is really that big. as far as i know, the default php configuration have limitations about memory use, file size, and size per request

Comment: I increased the size limit, but the problem still exists

Comment: the size was 128M and I increased it to be 2048M and the problem is not solved yet

Comment: the php default max_execution_time is 30s. Did you edit this settings too? and if you're data is that big, why not using queue function to handle it to run in background?